# How to align 2 element in a div with a fix size of the div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I'm trying to have the icon on the right side of the div lets say on 10% space of the div, and the title on 90% of the div regardless of the length of the title

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <nb-card >
        <nb-card-body class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
          <label for="icon" class="label col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{title}}</label>
          <nb-icon id="icon" pack='eva' icon='minus-square' name="minus-square"
                    status="{{status}}"></nb-icon>
        </nb-card-body>
      </nb-card>
</div>
```

Which classes should be added to perform this fixed layout?

Comment: You can use flex-basis:90% and flex_basis:10%. P.S. do you use bootstrap 4?

Comment: Yep, dose bootstrap had any embeded flex-basis label?

Comment: Check the documentation. For example col-sm-4 has flex:0 0 33.333333%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap, then you can make use of the Bootstrap Grid system, utilizing the `row` and `col` class respectively. You can then make your own custom classes and give them the CSS properties to make the spacing you desire.

For instance, I simply used margin to determine the space between the text and the button.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-rounded-border">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center text-left">
            <label id="title">Title</label><button type="button" class="btn-success btn-style">-</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--
    You don't need this section below,
    it's simply to test the title in different lengths
-->
<br />
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn-primary" id="toggleBtn">Toggle Title</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content-rounded-border {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-style {
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**jQUery (to utilize the toggle button):**

```
$('#toggleBtn').on("click", function() {
    let titleVal = $('#title').html();

    if( titleVal == "Title" ) {
        $('#title').html("Super Long Title Omg");
    } else if( titleVal == "Super Long Title Omg") {
        $('#title').html("Title");
    }
});
```

Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/RwrGPNY).

Ignore The container I'm using, that's not important. I was simply replicating the visual of your own container. What's important is the Grid and the spacing of the elements you desire inside.

**Snippet:**

```js
$('#toggleBtn').on("click", function() {
 let titleVal = $('#title').html();
 
 if( titleVal == "Title" ) {
  $('#title').html("Super Long Title Omg");
 } else if( titleVal == "Super Long Title Omg") {
  $('#title').html("Title");
 }
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.content-rounded-border {
 display: block;
 width: 90%;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-top: 6%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-style {
 margin-left: 5%;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-rounded-border">
 <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center text-left">
   <label id="title">Title</label><button type="button" class="btn-success btn-style">-</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!--
 You don't need this section below,
 it's simply to test the title in different lengths
-->
<br />
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn-primary" id="toggleBtn">Toggle Title</button>
 </div>
</div>
```